# Implementing a correct equality operator via pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am exposing a C++ class using pybind11. I want to expose an `__eq__` method. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
pybind11_class.def("__eq__", [](const MyClass &self, const myClass &other) {
    return self.value == other.value;
});
```

The problem is that this results in a type error when comparing to objects of other types, whereas the correct behavior in that situation is for there to be no error and for the equality to evaluate to false.

How do I correctly implement the equality operator? Ideally I'd like to define only one method overload, to avoid polluting the docstring exposed by pybind11.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of attempting to directly define the `__eq__` method, tell pybind that you want an equality method by defining `pybind11::self == pybind11::self`. It will take care of the "return false for other types"  semantics:

```
auto pybind11_class = pybind11::class_<...>(...);

pybind11_class.def(pybind11::self == pybind11::self);
pybind11_class.def(pybind11::self != pybind11::self);
```

For this to work, your C++ class must have `operator==` and `operator!=` operators and you must `#include <pybind11/operators.h>`.

Comment: @pnklein I'm not sure what element is missing. Define an == operator for your class and in your pybind method bind to it using the syntax I provide in the answer.

Comment: I got it to work in the meanwhile.  Perhaps note the need for #include <pybind11/operators.h>

Comment: Also, perhaps instructions on how to get __hash__ defined?

Comment: I do not get how the expression `pybind11::self == pybind11::self` and `pybind11::self != pybind11::self` can lead to operator overloading. Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.  In the binding code for the class, include the equality operator for the class as shown.

```
#include <pybind11/operators.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(name, m)
{
    py::class_<Data>(m, "Data")
        .def(py::self == py::self)
        .def(py::self != py::self);
}
```

Then in the class code add a friend as an equality operator override

```
class Data
{
public:

    bool friend operator==(const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs)
    {
        if (strcmp(lhs.data->tag, rhs.data->tag)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool friend operator!=(const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs)
    {
        if (strcmp(lhs.data->tag, rhs.data->tag)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is essentially the same as the answer posted above, which while correct, does not include reference to an issue experienced during compilation, i.e. the equality operator override referenced by the pybind11 binding code must be implemented as a friend in order to compile.  The standard C++ equality override is a separate entity and occupies the primary override namespace.

Note that the sample code shown here is not working code, the balance of the body of the implementations has been omitted.